# MultiView2.ActiveViewIndex doesn't change the view

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

Language: VB,
Environment: Visual Studio 2010

I have a DropDownList in a MultiView2:View2, and if the selected index of the DropDown is 5, then the view should change to View3, but doesn't work, I have AutoPostBack property of the DropDown set to True, the two views both have UpdatePanels within them. I have this within an IF statement obviously, and everything else fires, besides the `MultiView2.ActiveViewIndex = 1`.
This is my code so far...
**This is under the SelectedIndexChanged event**

```
    If drpDownSecurityQuestion.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        txtAnswer.Enabled = False
    ElseIf drpDownSecurityQuestion.SelectedIndex > 0 And drpDownSecurityQuestion.SelectedIndex < 5 Then
        txtAnswer.Enabled = True
    ElseIf drpDownSecurityQuestion.SelectedIndex = 5 Then
        txtAnswer.Enabled = False
        drpDownSecurityQuestion2.SelectedIndex = 5
        MultiView2.ActiveViewIndex = 1
    End If
```

Comment: I think you have something wrong in using UpdatePanen. Explain how you have been using dropdown, updatepanel and multiview. Tell what is insode what?

Comment: OK, so I have the DropDown in the UpdatePanel, and the UpdatePanel inside the View, and the View inside the MultiView. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it's clear. You can't raise post inside updatepanel.

add postback trigger to to your updatepanel:

Comment: The DropDown is a trigger on the UpdatePanel

Comment: will your drodown raise event if you move it outside updatepanel scope?

Comment: Yes, when outside the UpdatePanel and MultiView, when the SelectedIndex is changed, the MultiView2.ActiveIndex fires. But obviously the reason for having it in the UpdatePanel is so that only that part is updated, not the whole page.

Comment: OK, I'll tell you what I'm trying to achieve, and how I have set it up. The user creates an account, and a security question is needed, the user selects one from the DropDown and puts the answer in the textbox below, there is an option of writing their own question, which is what the second view is for. And before the security question there is a Password textbox, which resets when the SelectedIndex is changed of the DropDown, when not in the UpdatePanel, which I don't want.

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for getting back to me all the time so I am going to mark your post as the right answer and vote it up, but I have it fixed now, I just changed the controls. I put the MultiView in the UpdatePanel.